# Plugin to open file at eof

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm tryng to create a plugin that opens a .log file associated with a file i'm editing. I was able to open the file but could not make the cursor move to end of file, unless I run the code again when the file is already open.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class OpenlogCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        if os.path.isfile(self.view.file_name()[:-3]+"log"):
            a=sublime.active_window().open_file(self.view.file_name()[:-3]+"log")
        a.run_command("move_to", {"to": "eof"})
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work unless the file is already open is because the loading of a file is asynchronous; the command to open the file returns right away and the file is loaded in the background if it's not already open.

Thus the first time you run the command, the `move_to` command does nothing because it's already at the end of an empty buffer, but when the file has already been loaded it does what you expect.

To get around that, you need to detect if the file is still loading and defer the call to jump to the end of the file until after it's finished. An example of that is the following:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import os

class OpenLogCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        log_name = self.view.file_name()[:-3] + "log"
        log_view = self.view.window().open_file(log_name)

        if log_view.is_loading():
            log_view.settings().set("_goto_eol", True)
        else:
            log_view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "eof"})

    def is_enabled(self):
        fname = self.view.file_name()
        if fname is not None and not fname.endswith(".log"):
            return os.path.isfile(fname[:-3] + "log")

        return False

class OpenLogListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        if view.settings().get("_goto_eol", False):
            view.settings().erase("_goto_eol")
            view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "eof"})
```

An issue with your existing version of this is that the `file_name()` method returns `None` if the file has not been saved to disk yet. Thus if you run that command on an unsaved file it will generate an error in the console. This is harmless, but a little unclean since it might be a red herring if you have other problems and happen to see those errors in the console.

Here the command will only enable itself if the file has been saved to stop that kind of problem. It will also only enable itself if it's not already a log file (since that would be redundant), and where an associated log file actually exists.

When a command is disabled, you can't execute it. That means that it also won't show up in the Command Palette and it will appear grayed out in menus (assuming you've added it to either of those).

When you run the command, it first calls `open_file` to open the associated log file, and then asks the view "Are you still loading?". When the view says NO, it means that the file is already open, and so we can immediately jump to the end of the file.

If the view says YES to this question, we then set a temporary setting in the view so that we know that when the contents of this view is finished loading, we want to jump to the end of the buffer.

The event listener asks every view as it's finished loading if it has this setting set, and when it does it will remove the setting and then jump to the end of the file.

---

[edit]

As mentioned in the comments below, the `move_to` command behaves slightly differently for a file that's already open versus a file that has just finished loading.

I'm not entirely sure why that's the case, but I suspect that there is some subtle interplay between the `on_load` notification being delivered right when the file content has been loaded but not yet displayed or something along those lines, although this is just a guess.

In any case, the most expedient fix would be to make a slight modification to the event listener by replacing that part of the code above with this instead:

```python
class OpenLogListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        if view.settings().get("_goto_eol", False):
            view.settings().erase("_goto_eol")
            sublime.set_timeout(lambda: view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "eof"}), 1)
```

This changes things up a bit so that the call to the `move_to` command effectively happens after all event handling has been completed. That seems to resolve the issue on my test machine, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I'm having a bit of problem with the move to eof command. If I press Ctrl+end in any buffer, it puts the cursor in the last line and the last line stays at the bottom of the page, maximizing the amount of text on the screen. With this code, it works this way if the .log file is already open. If it's not open yet, it puts the last line of text in the first line of the screen, showing no text at all, and I have to scroll up to see the text. I did a lot of searching on Google with no success so far. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Hmm interesting. I'm not sure why that's happening, although it seems suspicious. I edited the answer to provide a possible work-around. Let me know if that works for you or not.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!